# Simple math in T-SQL

Tags: t-sql

I am using a Scalar-Valued Function to find out if a user of the system has images, audio files or videos in their profile.

When I search through members I want to order the members by amount of media they have.  So for example a user with all media (videos, audio and images) would get 3, 1 point for each media they have.  If they have 2 media(images and video) but no audio they would get 2.  This would be listed after all the users that have all 3 media.

The stored procedure has this:

```
SELECT
a.MemberID,
a.UserName,
a.LastLogin,
a.City,
b.Abbr,
c.Country,
a.AvatarMed,
a.Gender,
sbuser.sf_MemberHasImages(a.MemberID),
sbuser.sf_MemberHasVideo(a.MemberID),
sbuser.sf_MemberHasAudio(a.MemberID),
d.Domain,
sbuser.sf_DisplayName(a.MemberID),
a.CreateDate,
a.Claimed,
a.ProfileTypeID,
a.Zip,
a.PhoneNbr,
a.PrPhone
FROM Member a
LEFT JOIN State b ON b.StateID = a.StateID
INNER JOIN Country c ON c.countryID = a.CountryID
INNER JOIN Region d ON d.RegionID = a.MemberREgionID
WHERE ProfileTypeID IS NOT NULL
AND (sbuser.sf_DisplayName(a.MemberID) LIKE @UserName + '%')
AND a.MemberID <> @MemberID
ORDER BY a.Claimed DESC, a.AvatarTiny DESC, sbuser.sf_MemberHasMedia(a.MemberID)
```

If you note the order by, it contains the following:

```
set ANSI_NULLS ON
set QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER FUNCTION [sbuser].[sf_MemberHasMedia](@MemberID bigint)

RETURNS BIT
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @OUTSTR INT
DECLARE @OUT1 BIT
DECLARE @OUT2 BIT
DECLARE @OUT3 BIT
SET @OUT1 = (SELECT CAST(COUNT(MemberAudioID) AS BIT) FROM MemberAudio
WHERE MemberID @MemberID)
RETURN @OUTSTR = @OUT1
END

RETURNS BIT
AS
BEGIN
SET @OUT2 = (SELECT CAST(COUNT(a.MemberImgID) AS BIT)
From MemberImg a
INNER JOIN MemberImgGallery b ON b.MemberImgGalleryID=a.MemberImgGalleryID
WHERE b.MemberID = @MemberID)
RETURN @OUTSTR = @OUTSTR + @OUT2
END

RETURNS BIT
AS
BEGIN
SET @OUT3 = (SELECT CAST(COUNT(MemberVideoID) AS BIT) FROM MemberVideo
WHERE MemberID = @MemberID)
RETURN @OUTSTR = @OUTSTR + @OUT3
END
```

I am lost in the logic of this, and it should be easy.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks,
Paul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've attempted to clean the syntax of the function up a little. The key point is that the return type of the function should be an INT instead of a BIT.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [sbuser].[sf_MemberHasMedia](@MemberID bigint)

RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @OUTSTR INT
    DECLARE @OUT1 INT
    DECLARE @OUT2 INT
    DECLARE @OUT3 INT

    SET @OUT1 = (SELECT CAST(COUNT(MemberAudioID) AS BIT) 
                 FROM MemberAudio
                 WHERE MemberID @MemberID)

    SET @OUT2 = (SELECT CAST(COUNT(a.MemberImgID) AS BIT)
                 FROM MemberImg a
                     INNER JOIN MemberImgGallery b 
                         ON b.MemberImgGalleryID=a.MemberImgGalleryID
                 WHERE b.MemberID = @MemberID)

    SET @OUT3 = (SELECT CAST(COUNT(MemberVideoID) AS BIT) 
                 FROM MemberVideo
                 WHERE MemberID = @MemberID)

    SET @OUTSTR = @OUT1 + @OUT2 + @OUT3
    RETURN @OUTSTR
END
```

Comment: Getting the following error: Msg 8117, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sf_MemberHasMedia, Line 25
Operand data type bit is invalid for add operator.

Comment: Need to change the datatypes for @OUT1, @OUT2 AND @OUT3 to be INT as well. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: That should happen without any additional code. If no results are found, each individual count will return 0 and the sum will also be 0.

Comment: I have 3 operations on the ORDER BY and it doesn't work.. remove one and it does.. am I missing something, or is there a limit to the amount of order by operations..?

Comment: Ordering by 3 columns *shouldn't* be an issue.

Comment: I put: ORDER BY a.Claimed DESC, a.AvatarTiny DESC, sbuser.sf_MemberHasMedia(a.MemberID) DESC and it doesn't order correctly but if I put: ORDER BY a.Claimed DESC, sbuser.sf_MemberHasMedia(a.MemberID) DESC then it does order correctly

Comment: Glad to help. Please comment again if you figure out the order issue. I'll be curious to know.